# App testing on iPhone, where is the crash log?

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, swift

I was finally able to put the app on my phone to test it but soon as I open the app, it crashes..It is written in swift. Is it even compatible on the iPhone yet? I'm currently running 7.0.4. Also is there any where I can access the crash logs? I tried to look in Devices -> Device logs, but didn't see my app in the logs.

Has anyone been able to get it working on their phone and how?

I made my own certificates and editted the info.plist to get it through xCode without dev account..but I don't think that matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get crash logs using **iPhone configuration utility** application.

you can download it from here : [http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1465](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1465.)

Comment: Thank you very much! Now to figure out what all of this means myself...before I come back here

Answer (score 1):

You can get the crash reports using the Xcode organizer.

1. Connect the device.
2. Open the Xcode organizer.
3. Select the devices tab (Xcode 5.1)
4. Select `Devices Logs` under the device.

This will also trigger the symbolication process of the crash reports, so you should see your class names, methods, filenames and line numbers a few seconds after selecting a crash report.

The top level `Device Logs` item will only show the crash reports of your devices, once you did the above steps to get the organizer to import the crash reports from a device.